# Decimal to Binary Conversion

Tags: c++, while-loop, evaluation, conditional-statements, boolean-expression

I was writing a function for conversion between Decimal and Binary base number systems and here's my original code:

```
void binary(int number)
{
    vector<int> binary;

    while (number == true)
    {
        binary.insert(binary.begin(), (number % 2) ? 1 : 0);
        number /= 2;
    }

    for (int access = 0; access < binary.size(); access++)
        cout << binary[access];
}
```

It didn't work however until I did this:

```
while(number)
```

what's wrong with

```
while(number == true)
```

and what's the difference between the two forms?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say `while (number)`, `number`, which is an `int`, is converted to type `bool`.  If it is zero it becomes `false` and if it is nonzero it becomes `true`.

When you say `while (number == true)`, the `true` is converted to an `int` (to become `1`) and it is the same as if you had said `while (number == 1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm still learning and type promotion is escaping me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code....

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define max 10000
#define RLC(num,pos) ((num << pos)|(num >> (32 - pos)))
#define RRC(num,pos) ((num >> pos)|(num << (32 - pos)))

void tobinstr(int value, int bitsCount, char* output)
{
    int i;
    output[bitsCount] = '\0';
    for (i = bitsCount - 1; i >= 0; --i, value >>= 1)
      {
             output[i] = (value & 1) + '0';
      }
}


  int main()
   {
    char s[50];
    tobinstr(65536,32, s);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
   }
```